# Why is java.util.ConcurrentModificationException being raised here?

Tags: java, exception, concurrentmodification

This exception rises up

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
    at noob.Prim_up_to.prim(Prim_up_to.java:72)
    at noob.Prim_up_to.<init>(Prim_up_to.java:21)
    at _ex.main(_ex.java:11)
```

Here is the relevant code: `http://pastebin.com/w6d0hyXb`

Why is it that this happens? I tried using iterator but to no avail. The same exception shows up nevertheless.

Comment: this is not an exact duplicate! The problem is a bit more complicated due to assignment of a list to another list.
i.e.:

It is not easy to spot but at some point in your code you make an assignment `ss = nss;`

but inside your `for loop` you call `nss.add(new Integer(npp-lrpp));`, 
so as `ss = nss` you indeed modify the collection while iterating over it!

Try using an iterator or deep copy `nss` to `ss`

Answer (score 1):

This exception gets raised when you modify an (in this case) ArrayList while iterating over it. If you must modify an ArrayList during the course of an iteration, consider using a `ListIterator`, which has an `add` and `remove` method.